# Autoscaling microservice in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I want to create something similar with this:

[image]

Basically I have a microservice and I want to scale the instances of it, but to use the same MongoDB container. These containers should be connected to a load balancer. How can I achieve this using Kubernetes?

Comment: Did the provided answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use k8s [HorizontalPodAutoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) to scale out your microservice as the demand goes up. When all of your nodes are filled up with microservices, you use [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) to scale out your node so more microservices can come online.